# Set (CSS background-image) image assets in Symfony 4

Tags: php, css, symfony, path, twig

I'm practicing with Symfony 4 and I am trying to show my images through CSS. Now when I run `npm run dev` it only compiles the CSS and JS files but not the images. I moved al the images to the `/assets/img/` folder.

Now I'm eager to know how I can work with the CSS paths to adapt to the Symfony environment. I only found solutions regarding Symfony 2 and 3 which are not working in this version. My CSS is:

```
.about-solution-about {
  background: url(/img/placeholder.jpg) no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 540px;
  height: 330px;
  padding-top: 40px;
}
```

The image is now in this location: `project/assets/img/placeholder.jpg`

Somehow I need to access this image in the public folder through the compiled app.css file. I know that the `app.css` and the `app.js` files are compiled and placed in the `/public/build/` folder.

Now, how do I compile or build  all the image assets to the `/public/build/` folder and recall those files in my CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The building of the regular CSS and JS assets in the `/assets/` folder are handled by the **Webpack Encore** `webpack.config.js` file in your project directory.

When you run the `npm run dev` command in your terminal the files `app.css` and `app.js` are compiled and placed in the `/public/build/` folder.

If you also want images included in the `/public/build/` folder you can make use of the **[Copy Webpack Plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/copy-webpack-plugin)**.

First, install the plugin with the `npm i -D copy-webpack-plugin` command in your terminal.

Then edit the `webpack.config.js` file in your home project folder.
Under the first line, add:

```
var CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
```

And then right before the Encore section ends with a semicolon `;`, add:

```
.addPlugin(new CopyWebpackPlugin([
        { from: './assets/img', to: 'img' }
    ]))
```

**JSFiddle** example of the whole file [here](https://jsfiddle.net/oct75jyu/1/).

Now, make sure that you have images in the `/assets/img/` folder.

Run the `npm run dev` command and you 'll see that all your images from the assets folder are now available in the `/public/build/img/` folder!!

In your example the correct path in your CSS would now be:

```
background: url(/build/img/placeholder.jpg) no-repeat center;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use cssrewrite filter within stylesheets twig tag / base twig /:

```
{% stylesheets 'source to css files' filter='cssrewrite' %}

{% endstylesheets %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there's no way to work with Assets in pure CSS code. I recommend you to set the background parameter in your HTML, where you actually can.
Hope you figure it out!